# Passing a variable from anchor click to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using opencart and got stuck.
What I am doing is sending some variable to ajax.
This is my data:

```
data: $('.product-block input[type=\'text\'], .product-block input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-block input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-block input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-block select, .product-block textarea'),
```

It is working fine.
But what I need to do is to replace the '.product-block' from picking a id from anchor click.

I have my id here

```
var id = $(this).attr('rel');
```

But I am unable to build the data source from this link.
I am using it like this:

```
data: $(id + ' input[type=\'text\']', id + ' input[type=\'hidden\']', ... ),
```

and tested this

```
data: $(id + ' input[type=\'text\']', + id + ' input[type=\'hidden\']', ... ),
```

But it is not working. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Just use `'.product-block input[type="text"]` as it is cleaner.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in the question shows how your strings are malformed.  What is the value of `id` anyway, how does it relate to the selector?  If it's an element's `id` then you also need a `#` in the string, but you're getting it from a `rel` value so it's not really clear to me.

Comment: data: $(id + ' input[type=\'text\'], + id + ' input[type=\'hidden\'], ... ), <<< as you wrote it I see 2 syntax errors regarding single quotes and concatenation.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I cannot as I need to send the input field to ajax, and when I use this it send all the product input field.

Comment: Jumping ahead a little.. Have you thought about `$.param('#'+id)`?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I have fixed it, maybe someone other has edited. :0

Comment: What I meant was replace `\'` with `"`.

Comment: @Malk how to use this?

Comment: @hjpotter92 but what about the product id?

Comment: `serialize()`, that's what I was thinking of. Check Wilmer's answer. [`$('*','#' + id).serialize()`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all ".product-block" occurrences and use `find()` it's simpler:

```
var id = "#" + $(this).attr('rel');
$(id).find('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'hidden\'], input[type=\'radio\']:checked,  input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, select, textarea');
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Also don't forget to use `serialize()` to "pull" the data from the form:

```
data: $(id).find(...).serialize() //removed ;
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Later how to pass that as in data to ajax?
Sorry, I am not good in jquery

Comment: It still does not post anything.

Comment: When I console log the complete find data, it shows Object[input property value = "bvbv" attribute value = "", input attribute value = "3"]

But it does not post anything to ajax.
The Post is empty. (Strange)?

Comment: do your inputs have name attributes?

Comment: When I tried data: $(id).find(...).serialize() 
it does not post anything.. But when I do this: var xy = $(id).find(...).serialize() and post to data : xy. It works.

Comment: Yes it has name attributes.

Comment: Ok, try console logging the id and $(id).find()

Comment: Actually it works.. 
var xy = find
and passing xy to data.. is this good solution?

Comment: Oh ok, yes it's better actually

Comment: Sure, I am using that :)

Comment: Great! Btw are the inputs and textareas all inside a form element?